# Is "homophobic" a noun?

Tags: word-usage

I've thought **homophobe** refers to *the people* and **homophobic** is just an *adjective*.
However I recently heard that **homophobic** is also used as a *noun* describing *the people who have homophobia*, meaning *homophobe*.

Is **homophobic** ― not *the homophobics*; I know this can be a noun ― used as a noun as well as an adjective?

Comment: If you *"know [plural **homophobics**] can be a noun"*, why would you think the singular form might not also be a noun?

Comment: In general, in English, you can nounify an adjective, verbify a noun, et al.  It isn't always the best choice of words, but it is usually understood, and many such constructions eventually make it into the "official" language.  (Consider, eg, that most people would hardly bat an eyelash hearing "John is a diabetic", rather than "John is diabetic".)

Answer (score 28):

In English, an adjective can act as a noun, where it stands for those described by the adjective.

> The Quick and the Dead
>
> The Fast and the Furious

etc.

Comment: Yes, good point. An *epileptic* is one who suffers epileptic fits, and a *diabetic* one who has diabetes.

Comment: @WS2: I don't think those forms are in current usage by medical professionals. The correct forms would be "a person with epilepsy" or "a person with diabetes", etc.

Comment: @R I would agree that they are perhaps not the most fashionable forms but the questioner asked whether an adjective such as *homophobic* is ever used as a noun. The answer is 'yes', and so are *epileptic*, *diabetic* and *schizophrenic*.

Comment: @R.. That's not because it's incorrect grammar. It's political correctness to remind the doctor that their patient is a full human being, is not just a disease vector.

Comment: I would disagree with this. The titles you wrote just omit the noun i.e. `The quick [people] and the dead [people]`. If they were nouns, the following wouldn't sound so strange: `there are some quick`, `there is a quick`.

Comment: @DanVerdolino There are dozens of examples besides the ones I mentioned. The adjective acts as the noun, but is not a noun. "The rich", "The poor", "The sick". This is common in cases where the adjective describes the category of nouns represented. The reason "rich", "poor", "sick", etc, are not considered nouns is because, as you mentioned, you can't say "a poor". Doesn't mean it's not acting as a noun in some cases though.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I have always thought of those terms as omitting but implying the noun. `The rich [people]` etc. This would work in most (all?) cases, but things break down in the examples I provided above when they are used as nouns.

Comment: @DanVerdolino So, if the noun is omitted but implied, wouldn't that mean that the adjective acts as the noun? But it is not a noun.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 No the noun would be the missing [people]. A noun is not necessary; it is a phrase and not meant to be a complete sentence anyway. There are other examples of implicit nouns such as "How many people are there?", "There are forty [people]". In this case, the answer is not a complete sentence without [people], which has been omitted and implied. "forty" is not a noun, rather an adjective of quantity.

Comment: @DanVerdolino So if I have a sentence: "The poor walked to work while the rich rode in limousines.", you're going to tell me that it's an incomplete sentence because I left out "people" twice? No. The adjective acts as the noun. It takes a verb. It functions as the subject of the sentence. It does everything _in that sentence_ that a noun would. What more could it possibly do? _It acts as a noun._

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I have always though of it implying the noun. In the case "There are forty.", would "forty" be a noun? I would say no, but not know where to draw the line.

Comment: @DanVerdolino As I said earlier: it might not BE a noun, but it ACTS as one. You draw the line depending on how much it acts like a noun. Once it acts like a noun in all possible noun cases, then it is a noun. If it cannot act like a noun for all possible noun uses then it must not BE a noun. But that doesn't stop it from acting like one.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I've changed my mind somewhat, and am inclined to agree with you about these examples. But they have evolved into nouns through their usage. Most of your examples are defined in dictionaries as nouns after years of use as such. I would still not consider *any* adj acting as a noun just because its noun is missing. Especially in the context of this question - since there is already the noun: "homophobe". It's been a pleasure

Comment: It is awkward to use the adjective as a noun when there is already a noun form of the word like in "homophobe."  For example, a xenophobe is someone who is xenophobic.  But it would be awkward to use xenophobic as a noun.  A hydrophobe is a molecule that resists water.  Do not call it a hydrophobic.

Comment: @MobyDisk You generally cannot call it * _a hydrophobic_. If you could, _hydrophobic_ would be a noun, but it isn't, it's an adjective. But as I've said ad nauseum, sometimes an adjective _acts_ as a noun.

Comment: I actually agree with Dan, the noun is implied, and the adjective itself does not become a noun. This is not a case of "if it quacks...", rather this is a case of "omitting the useless stuff to keep things short". Kind of like "Andy ate the burger, and drank the tea": the *and* is not the subject, the subject simply got omitted

Comment: @Raestloz I have never said that the adjective BECOMES a noun. And your example using _and_ is spurious. _and_ does not require you to repeat the subject; you can tack on as many _and_ clauses as you want and they all link back to the previous referent. That is totally different from this nounal adjective case. You can google it if you don't believe me and WS2 and bib.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: I propose the rule that the adjective should not act as a noun if a proper noun form already exists.  Such is the case with hydrophobic, xenophobic, homophobic.

Comment: @MobyDisk propose whatever rules you want. That doesn't change the fact that adjectives can act as nouns. You might not consider it the best word choice, but it's still grammatical.

Comment: I agree, and so does wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectival_noun_%28noun%29

There *is* a difference between adjectives coerced into acting as nouns via zero-derivation, and adjectives that have become full-fledged nouns - as pointed out, the former sound correct in some contexts, but awkward or even ungrammatical in others, where a dictionary-quality noun wouldn't. That said, absolutely any adjective *can* be (temporarily) nouned.

Answer (score 23):

All of the online dictionaries at *[onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=homophobic&ls=a)* list *homophobic* as an adjective and none list it as a noun.

As the poster notes, there is an accepted noun for a homophobic person, *homophobe*.

As Mr. Shiny and New notes, adjectives are often used as nouns. However, in most cases, this is limited to a collective or categorical usage as in his examples, such as *the fast and the furious*. You can say *the race goes to the swift*, but you cannot say *the race goes to a swift* (unless you are talking about the bird).

As @WS2 points out, adjectives are often used as nouns to refer to someone who has a condition, such as *a diabetic*. This type of usage can refer to individuals or a whole category, and can take a definite or indefinite article. These seem to be limited to cases where there is not a separate accepted noun for the thing that has the adjective's quality.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, it should be noted that this usage is going out of style, and is actively rejected by some people as dehumanizing. This is especially the case with words that name a person according to a disease or disability they have or where the adjective-as-noun form has been used to actively dehumanize ("illegals", "homosexuals", etc.).

Comment: Doesn't usage often become proper even if it didn't start quite that way? Here, I agree, two different words, one adj, one noun. But if common usage treat homophobic as noun, at some point, it's accepted as such.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Words and usage do evolve, but since there is an accepted term, I'm not sure what the adjectival form used as a noun adds. There is no difference in meaning or tone.